# Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, svg, vuejs2

I already asked the question but I think the title was wrong.

I am new to VueJs and using [vue-aplayer](https://github.com/SevenOutman/vue-aplayer) to play audio files on my site. The player requires svg icons that are in the assets folder but I am getting error while running it.

```
const requireAssets = require.context('../assets', false, /\.svg$/)
  console.log(requireAssets.keys())
  const SVGs = requireAssets.keys().reduce((svgs, path) => {
    const inlineSvg = requireAssets(path)
    const [raw, viewBox, d] = inlineSvg.match(/^<svg.+?viewBox="(.+?)".*><path.+?d="(.+?)".*><\/path><\/svg>$/)

    svgs[path.match(/^.*\/(.+?)\.svg$/)[1]] = {
      viewBox,
      d
    }
    return svgs
  }, {})
```

The error it displays is

```
app.js:6489 Uncaught TypeError: Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method.
    at _nonIterableRest (app.js:6489)
    at _slicedToArray (app.js:6487)
    at app.js:6514
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at Module../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./resources/js/vue-aplayer/components/aplayer-icon.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
```

I logged the requireAssets and it is getting the values like

```
0: "./loading.svg"
1: "./lrc.svg"
2: "./menu.svg"
3: "./no-repeat.svg"
```

I tried using keys.map() and Object.keys(requireAssets).map but nothing came close to solution. If I comment the icon import code, the players loads fine but without icons.

Full page code:

```
<template>
  <svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="100%" version="1.1" :viewBox="svg.viewBox" width="100%"
       :style="style">
    <use xlink:href="#aplayer-${type}"></use>
    <path class="aplayer-fill" :d="svg.d"></path>
  </svg>
</template>

<script>
  const requireAssets = require.context('../assets/', false, /\.svg$/)
  // console.log(requireAssets.keys())
  console.log(requireAssets.keys())
  const SVGs = requireAssets.keys().reduce((svgs, path) => {
    const inlineSvg = requireAssets(path)
    const svgMatches = inlineSvg.match(/^<svg.+?viewBox="(.+?)".*><path.+?d="(.+?)".*><\/path><\/svg>$/)
    if(!svgMatches) return [];
    const [raw, viewBox, d] = svgMatches
    svgs[path.match(/^.*\/(.+?)\.svg$/)[1]] = {
      viewBox,
      d
    }
    return svgs
  }, {})

  export default {
    props: ['type'],
    computed: {
      svg () {
        let icon = this.type
        if (this.type === 'prev' || this.type === 'next') {
          icon = 'skip'
        }
        return SVGs[this.type] || {}
      },
      style () {
        if (this.type === 'next') {
          return {
            transform: 'rotate(180deg)',
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: `inlineSvg.match(...)` is probably returning null

Comment: I upvoted your answer but I didn't understand. Do you want further info on the code? PS. It is returning null but I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex will return `null` if it can't match a svg syntax. So you should test your result before destructuring it to avoid runtime error.

```js
const requireAssets = require.context('../assets', false, /\.svg$/)
  console.log(requireAssets.keys())
  const SVGs = requireAssets.keys().reduce((svgs, path) => {
    const inlineSvg = requireAssets(path)
    const svgMatches = inlineSvg.match(/^<svg.+?viewBox="(.+?)".*><path.+?d="(.+?)".*><\/path><\/svg>$/)
    if(!svgMatches) return [];
    const [raw, viewBox, d] = svgMatches
    svgs[path.match(/^.*\/(.+?)\.svg$/)[1]] = {
      viewBox,
      d
    }
    return svgs
  }, {})
```

Comment: I tried this, it loads the player but doesn't load the icons it is supposed to import. I am going to post the whole code for easier understanding by editing my question.